# What's an acceptable latency for service/message bus

Tags: amazon-ec2, architecture, rabbitmq, latency, microservices

I'm developing a simple RPC style message bus where microservices will live on different virtualized machines.

I'm just testing a simple proof of concept using c4.large instances on EC2 for RabbitMQ, the server and the client.

I'm noticing round trips to the server and back are ~100ms with ~20ms for connecting to the amqp server and another ~80ms for returning a simple string.

This seems quite high to have an overhead of 100ms for each RPC request. Is there a typical acceptable latency for this style of architecture? Should I be looking at different tools?

Answer (score 4):

A message bus is typically used in applications to support **asynchronous processing**. A very simple example of this would be sending emails in response to a state change that happened in the application.

**In this regard, 100ms is quite fast.**

If you're trying to keep synchronous operations in your application fast, you won't get happy with making a message bus part of it.

Note that the above statement refers to external message buses. In-process message delivery mechanisms can be built with much less latency, but this is probably not what you need in the context of a microservices architecture.

> Should I be looking at different tools?

No, you have appropriate tools for a microservices architecture. But you should ask yourself the following questions:

- Is a microservices architecture the right choice for my application?
- If yes, do I have suitable service boundaries?